# Export table from MS SQL server to MySQL on Linux using only command line utilities

Tags: mysql, sql-server, linux, csv

I have a single table with 600,000 rows that I would like to migrate to MySQL.

I'm on Linux so I can't use the Microsoft SQL server GUI.

The MS SQL server instance is running inside a Docker container on my local machine and I'm using sqlcmd as the client shell.

So far I tried exporting the table to a CSV and then importing it inside MySQL but it seems like that isn't as easy as I thought.

These are some of the problems I encountered:

1. I couldn't find a way to export the table schema so I had to copy it manually.
2. Exported CSV has empty fields `,,` and MySQL produces an error when importing since it doesn't automatically recognise them as `NULL`.
3. Strings are not enclosed in quotes `''` and produce an error.

Is there an easier way of doing this?

P.S. I'm aware that there are similar questions already asked but none of them have good answers and most of them assume access to the Microsoft SQL server GUI application.

Comment: @KenWhite The title of the question is "Using only command line utilities" and you marked this as a duplicate with a link to a question that shows the GUI tools.